# Machine Learning Classification: Target variable almost completely one class

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a target variable which can be either 0 or 1, and 99.34% of it is 0 (about 50,000 entries in total). Logistic regression and naive bayes both just predicted all zeroes. Does anyone have a suggestion for this type of problem? I would like to determine feature importance.
Cheers

edit: I have about 10 features to predict with

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to give weights to the training examples, so that examples of class 1 count for more in the loss function than examples of class 0. I'm not sure what language/library you are using, but for example in scikit-learn's [LogisticRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) there is an argument called `class_weight` that takes care of this for you (either by setting it to `'balanced'` or by choosing it yourself). Or if you've implemented the logistic regression from scratch you can easily add these weights to your loss function yourself; it doesn't make the gradient computation any more complicated.